# How to access data in processing() object

Tags: processing

I am trying to use a class in processing that will store tuples. I cannot figure out how to access the data in the object `hello`. I get an error with the following. How do I access `hello.x`?

```
class xy
{
  float x,y;
  xy(float _x, float _y)
  {
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
  }
} 


xy hello = new xy(2,2);
println(hello.x);

exit()
```

Comment: What exact error do you get? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into processing verbatim and it worked fine with the addition of a semicolon after exit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of the missing semi mentioned in the comments above, your code looks like it should work.

You may want to specify the `x` and `y` attributes as public if you are planning to directly access them (though commands like `hello.x`), but I would encourage you to follow Object Oriented Design and make them private, then access them through `get` and `set` methods (ie `hello.getX()` instead of `hello.x`).

In either case, you don't need to create your own class for tuples in Processing, you can just use the provided [PVector](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) class, which behaves just like you seem to be after!

Hope this helps. Let me know if anything was unclear or you need further explanation.